# Декоратор времени для генератора

Tags: python-3.x

Не могу сообразить, как написать декоратор, чтобы засекал время выполнения функции-генератора.
Для обычной функции все ясно:

```
def decor(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        time_start = time.time()
        f = func(*args,**kwargs)
        time_finish = time.time()-time_start
        print(time_finish)
        return f
    return wrapper
```

Однако, если применить это к генератору, возвращает, насколько я понимаю, не время выполнения, а время создания объекта генератора.

Нашел вот такое решение:

```
t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt="list(f(50))", setup="from __main__ import f")
print t1.timeit()
```

Но хочется понимать, как самому написать.
Понимаю, что нужно как то просуммировать время выполнения для всех элементов генератора, но как сделать - не сообразжу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Python >= 3.3 я бы просто заюзал `yield from` (это почти как `yield` в цикле `for`, но умнее)

```
import time

def decor(func):
    def generator_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time_start = time.time()
        gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
        yield from gen
        time_finish = time.time()-time_start
        print(time_finish)
    return generator_wrapper

@decor
def myfunc():
    for i in range(1, 4):
        time.sleep(i)
        yield i
    time.sleep(1.77)  # просто так

print(list(myfunc()))
```

Вывод:

```
7.775537967681885
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно перегрузить метод `__next__`, вызываемый при попытке получить следующий элемент генератора:

```
import time

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen

    def __next__(self):
        start = time.time()
        value = next(self.gen)
        print(time.time() - start)
        return value

def timer(fn):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return Timer(fn(*args, **kwargs))
    return inner
```